# Проверка на возрастающую последовательнoсть

Tags: c++, числовые-последовательности

Сделал проверку на ввод чисел по возрастанию,вот только хотелось сделать так,чтобы если числа введены не по возрастанию,то ввести числа заново. У меня получилось,только не совсем корректно. Проблема с while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>          
#include <string> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int i = 0;
int u = 0;
const int dequeSize = 10;

//Первый дек   
std::deque<int> myDeque(dequeSize);

cout << "Введите элементы дека" << endl;
for (i = 0; i<dequeSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Введенный дек [" << i << "] = ";
    while(!(cin>>myDeque[i])) 
{
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    cout<<"ОШИБКА"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите число:  ";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.sync();  
}

}



for (i = 0; i < (dequeSize - 1); i++)

    if (myDeque[i] > myDeque[i + 1])
        break;

if (i == (dequeSize - 1)){

    cout << "Sorted";
}else{

    cout << "Not Sorted";

}

//////Проблема Здесь//////


while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))){

    cout << "Введите элементы дека" << endl;
for (i = 0; i<dequeSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Введенный дек [" << i << "] = ";
    while(!(cin>>myDeque[i])) 
{
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~"<<endl;
    cout<<"ОШИБКА"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите число:  ";
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cin.clear(); 
    cin.sync();  
}
}
}
```

Comment: В чем выражается проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том,что когда срабатывает while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))), то выдает ввести заново числа,это ладно,но вот если ввожу по возрастанию ,то все равно выдает ввести дек заново т.е цикл зацикливается,мне нужно ,чтобы если был введен не правильный дек т.е не по возрастанию,то перейти к циклу while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))) ,и в этом цикле был рабочая проверка на возрастание и если введен не по возрастанию,то ввести дек заново. Надеюсь понял меня)

Comment: Ничего непонятно. %-)

Comment: Смотри,мне нужно так, я ввожу дек,если он не возрастает,то его нужно написать заново.Вот хочу циклом while,у меня не получается.Получается бесконечный цикл

Comment: Ну так посмотри на условие прекращение цикла и сравни с тем, что нужно.

Comment: Я уже не соображаю)Помоги пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых: зачем вам дважды писать один и тот же код? Не проще ли сделать функцию? А еще лучше переписать так, чтобы цикл while не повторялся.

Во-вторых, я так понимаю вы хотите, чтобы, если последовательность введена успешна, то код завершился, так? В этом случае почему у вас условие:

```
while(!(i == (dequeSize - 1))){
```

Зачем сдесь while? Сдесь нужен if.

В-третьих, смотрите пунк во-первых.

Comment: C if пробовал, делает проверку 1 раз.

Comment: Ну да, верно. А в чем проблема?

Comment: Мне нужно ,чтобы он выдавал до тех пор,пока я не введу по возрастанию

Comment: А вот для этого я и писал: смотри пункт во-первых!!! Ну вот хорошо, ты хочешь, чтобы цикл проверял твои цифры и требовал ввод, пока не будет верный результат? Так? Окей, где проверка ввода в теле while? У тебя проверка зажата между двумя ОДИНАКОВЫМИ!! циклами for с предложениями ввода, но не относится ни к одному из них и выполняется ровно 1 раз за программу.  Просто рацианализируйте свой код и проблема решится сама собой.

Comment: Я так понял, нужно на if заменить и немного еще подправить сам код,Да?

Answer (score 0):

Если рационализировать код, то никакой if и не понадобится. Еще раз: у тебя два абсолютно одинаковых участка кода - зачем их повторять, если просто этот участок можно включить в цикл while (лучше, конечно в do while) и добавить туда проверку условия. Объем кода и операций еще уменьшится, если проверку организовать по ходу ввода, а не отдельным циклом.

Вот как сделал бы я:

```
int i = 0;
size = 10;
do {
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        if (i > 0 && arr[i] < arr[i - 1])
            break;
    }
} while (i < size);
```

Сравните это с вашей конструкцией.

Comment: Ой, хотел написать коммент, но не туда нажал.

Comment: А, и так сойдет.

Comment: Верно)Сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо,очень сильно выручили меня.